# How can i decode hash value in laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, encryption, laravel-5, decode

I have to convert my hash password into string.

here is my code.

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;
     use DB;
     use Auth;
     use Input;
     use Session;
     use Route;
     use Crypt;
     use Redirect;
     use Illuminate\Http\Request;
     use Illuminate\Http\Dispatcher; 

      $userdata = array(
                'email'     => $email,
                'password'  =>  Crypt::decrypt($password)
            );
```

when i use Crypt::decrypt i get error .
error-

```
DecryptException in BaseEncrypter.php line 45:
The payload is invalid.
```

Can any one suggest me how can i do that?

Thanks.

Comment: are you using Crypt::encrypt for encryption?

Comment: Crypto hashes are one-way functions, in that given a hash, it is practically impossible to get back the original text. See more here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function

Comment: Password string MUST be NOT DECRYPTABLE! Otherwise it's same as keeping password in plain text.

Comment: you can use Crypt::decrypt only on the strings which are encrypted using crypt::encrypt, so my suggesting is encrypt password using Crypt::encrypt

Comment: @Akshay I'm  not using Crypt::encrypt .

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `Crypt::decrypt()`

```
$value = Crypt::decrypt($encrypted);
```

> **Note : You must decrypt the value with the same key used to encrypt it.**
>
> Laravel's encryption routines use `Config::get('app.key')` for encryption. This happens internally. Since this value is different for every Laravel application then the application that encrypts a value must also decrypt the value.
>
> Or ...
>
> The application must call `Crypt::setKey()` prior to `decrypting` to match the key to the value used for encrypting. See Setting the Encryption Key.

***To  Encryption use***

```
Crypt::setKey($key);
```

> This key will be used for subsequent `Crypt::encrypt()` and `Crypt::decrypt()` calls.

Comment: Thanks Abdulla   It is possible to Use Crypt::decrypt(); 

because i got error when i used like that.

Comment: So that you have to **Encrypt the value**

Comment: Okay so i have to first convert my Hash value into Encrypt value or always store password with Encrypt value and  than i use Decrypt() function.

Comment: as per my knowledge in Laravel 5.1, support for Crypt::setKey has been dropped @Abdulla

Comment: Thanks every one . now i use Crypt::encrypt($password) for encrypt my password when user registration  and convert into descrypt with  Crypt::decrypt($userdata['password']); i finally i got my descrypt password.

Comment: Got this working, except you need to make the saved value a `longtext` in the database =) #forfurtherreaders